# I got MongoDB error after running : npx prisma db push

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, prisma

[The error after typing the command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcdnW.png)

I've checked my MongoDB url, it's correct.
The env files id properly linked.
How to resolve this?

This is my schema.prisma:

[Prisma Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE5qU.png)

This is how my .env looks like:

[.env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faYnx.png)

I've replaced the original values with dummy variables:

I tried checking the .env variables names, the username ,password, everything is correct.

I also tried npx prisma generate, but it brought new error:

[npx prisma generate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXKNk.png)

When i directly tried to replace the DATABASE_URL in schema with the actual url, this error turned up:

[error after replacing Database_url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4Ng3.png)

Edit : Creating a new user resolved it.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Please, write your code directly in the post. It is easier to analyze it or copy it to check how it works. If there is too much code try to synthesise your question. A good formulation of a question is half of the answer :-). you a re doing a good jib. keep going.

Answer (score 1):

Try to manually load your variable, for example using [`dontenv`](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv):

```js
    import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
    
    dotenv.config() // Load the environment variables
    console.log(`The connection URL is ${process.env.DATABASE_URL}`)
```

Referenced from [prisma docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/more/development-environment/environment-variables)

Comment: Got this : The connection URL is undefined